# INNO setup using registry value in DefaultDirName

Tags: inno-setup

I am writing an add-on to an other application. To install the add-on I need to read an registry key of the application the add-on is for. Depending on if the application is installed on 32 or 64 bit Windows the folder I have to install the dll to is Different.

I am looking for a solution to this problem:
How can I use the variable string I get from the registry key in to the DefaultDirName?

I have this:

```
#define DefaultRegistryKey64 'some regKey'
#define DefaultRegistryKey32 'Other RegKey'
[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppSetupname}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppVerName={#MyAppsetupname} {#MyAppVersion}
AppCopyright=Company Name
AppPublisher=Company Name
AppPublisherURL=http://someurl
AppSupportURL=http://someur
VersionInfoVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={code:getOSDefaultDirName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppSetupname}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=../StringSplitter Setup
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Code]
getOSDefaultDirName (Param: String): string;
 begin
 if Iswin64 then begin
  result := '{#DefaultDirName64}';
 end;
end;
```

Comment: What specific problem do you have ? Simply use [`RegQueryStringValue`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerystringvalue) function to get a `REG_SZ` or `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value from registry and return it from your function (which is missing its `function` keyword now).

Comment: That was just the little help I needed :-)